# Reconciling EventLog ApiTotalUsage with RestApi

Tags: eventlogfile, event-monitoring

Summer 23 rolling around and time to verify we don't have any legacy APIs at Version 21-30 ([which are being retired](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_upcoming_retirement.htm&release=242&type=5))

Per instructions, I used the [EventLogFile Browser](https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/event_log_files?daterange=2023-02-15%20to%202023-02-15&eventtype=ApiTotalUsage&interval=daily) to create a CSV and from there, I created a Pivot table on column `API Version`. *Note that one has to look at several days of data as not all 3rd party apps make API calls every day.*

Results showed API calls from Version `22 - 49` *(uh-oh)*

Yet when I looked at the CSV from `RestAPI` (we have Shield Event Monitoring), I could see URIs at Version 53.0.

Why were these not included in `ApiTotalUsage`?  Am I looking at the right data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce, in their wisdom, defines [event log file `ApiTotalUsage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_apitotalusage.htm) as collecting events up to V49.0 but no more.

> API Total usage events contain details about Platform SOAP API, Platform REST API, and Bulk API requests (for API versions **up to and including v49.0**).

Thus, your API calls at V50+ won't be included in this event log file but will appear in other log files such as [`REST Api`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_restapi.htm)

`ApiTotalUsage` is hence an ideal tool to help identify about-to-be-retired API versions but otherwise shouldn't be relied on for overall statistics.